# Printers from multiple workgroups

Tags: windows, printer, domain

I have a windows laptop that is on one domain at my office but I'd also like to be able use the printers on my home workgroup when I'm at home. Is there any way to do this, such as maybe having different "profiles" I can activate depending on where I am.

thanks,

Jeff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK once a printer is installed, it stays installed until deleted.

Which means that at the office you can print to the office printers, and at home to the home printer. Should one printer be unavailable, under normal circumstances, the print job should wait in the print queue for that printer until it becomes available, no profiles needed.

Beyond this theory, in reality heaps of problems can exist with print drivers.

Does this answer your problem?
If not, please specify also, in addition to the problem description, your O/S and the involved printer models.

**EDIT**

If you would like to have a default printer suggested automatically as a function of the current network you are connected to, see the following two references.

Freeware : [Set Default Printer based on the Network that the System Connected](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/printing/SET_DEFAULT_PRINTER.aspx)
Commercial : [Easy Net Switch](http://www.easynetswitch.com/switch-default-printer.html) ($29.95)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Do I not need to be on the same workgroup as my home printers to print to them? That's where my problem comes in - I didn't want to have to manually switch between my work domain and home workgroup.

Comment: When printing you need to specify the printer to print to. Both the office and home printers will be in the list, so there is no problem. If you would like to have a default printer suggested automatically from the current network, see my edited answer.

Comment: For some reason, I was under the impression that I needed to be in the same workgroup as a printer to print to it. I couldn't browse my workgroup for printers because it tried to browse my work's domain, but when I manually typed in the printer name (which I should've just tried to begin with), it worked. Thank you.